# Single Report - Multiple Designs in NAV 2016?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2016

Is it possible to create multiple designs for a single report in NAV 2016? If yes than how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [Custom Report Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav-app/ui-how-create-custom-report-layout)?

Through object designer it is not possible though.

Comment: Yes, am looking for custom report layout. Suppose there are multiple companies in NAV and I want to display same report with different design in all different companies, can it be possible then to create different report design.

Comment: Yes. This was intention of this functionality. Check the link.